# Bash scripting: How to display month of date modified of a certain folder and arrange jpegs in html file based on that

Tags: html, bash, shell

This script looks inside every folder in a folder and creates a thumbnail. That thumbnail is then outputted to an html file to be viewable in a browser. Where it says

```
<div class="month_txt">"$DATE_OF_MONTH "</div>
```

I would like it to display the month of what the original folder says the last time the file was modified. It would then group all of those findings underneath the same header of that month.

**Generates a thumbnail based on a folder**

```
sourcedir=~/Desktop/AD
targetdir=~/Desktop/OUT
SHOW=~/Desktop/OUT/show.html
targetsubdir_counter=1

cd $sourcedir

cat << 'EOF' >$SHOW
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
EOF


for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print | egrep -v "^\.$")
do

    cd $dir

    if [ $targetsubdir_counter -lt 10 ]
    then
        targetsubdir_name="0$targetsubdir_counter"
    else
        targetsubdir_name="$targetsubdir_counter"
    fi
    newdir="$targetdir/$dir" 
    newdir="$targetdir/$targetsubdir_name" 
    mkdir -p $newdir

    for file in "*300x250.jpg"
    do
        cp $file $newdir/thumb.jpg
         cat << 'EOF' > $newdir/preview.html 
<!DOCTYPE html>
</html>
EOF
        textfilename=$(echo $file | sed 's/\(.*\)_300x250.jpg$/\1/')
        #echo "$sourcedir/$dir" > $newdir/$textfilename


    done   

        cat <<EOM >> $SHOW
     <div class="box">

EOM  
    echo '<div class="month_txt">"$DATE_OF_MONTH "</div>' >> $SHOW
    echo '<div class="info"><p class="groupAnimated shorten-name">'$textfilename'</p></div>' >> $SHOW
      echo '<a href="'$newdir'/preview.html" target="_blank">' >> $SHOW
     echo '<img src="'$newdir'/thumb.jpg" height="250" width="300"/></a> </div>' >> $SHOW
}

    )

    cd ..
    (( targetsubdir_counter = targetsubdir_counter + 1 ))
done

cat << 'EOF' >>$SHOW
    </body>
</html>
EOF
```

**EXAMPLE**

FOLDER_A FOLDER_B FOLDER_C FOLDER_D FOLDER_E

### AUGUST

FOLDER_A_IMAGE FOLDER_C_IMAGE

### SEPTEMBER

FOLDER_D_IMAGE

### DECEMBER

FOLDER_E_IMAGE

### JANUARY

FOLDER_B_IMAGE

Comment: IMO, i think it is better to write a small python script to generate the file. Using shell script to generate a html template is brittle and it would be difficult to extend/enhance in the future. Python with template strings would be way more readable.